Unable to add keys with ssh-agent plugin in zsh
I just installed arch, and I am trying to configure my shell, zsh.
I am currently using zinit as my plugin manager with powerlevel10k.
I was trying to automate the activation of the ssh-agent and the addition of keys to it.
This is my current .zshrc file:
neofetch

# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay close to the top of ~/.config/zsh/.zshrc.
# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# Set the directory to store zinit and plugins
# ---  Defined in the .zshenv file

# Download Zinit if it's not there yet
if [ ! -d "$ZINIT_HOME" ]; then
    mkdir -p -- $ZINIT_HOME:h
    git clone https://github.com/zdharma-continuum/zinit "$ZINIT_HOME"
fi

# Source/Load zinit
source "${ZINIT_HOME}/zinit.zsh"

# Add in Powerlevel10k
zinit ice depth=1; zinit light romkatv/powerlevel10k

# Add in zsh plugins
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-completions
zinit light zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions
zinit light Aloxaf/fzf-tab

# Add in snippet
zinit snippet OMZP::git
zinit snippet OMZP::sudo
zinit snippet OMZP::archlinux
zinit snippet OMZP::command-not-found
zinit snippet OMZP::ssh-agent

# Load completions
autoload -U compinit && compinit

# Replay all cached completions ( recommended by documentation )
zinit cdreplay -q

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.config/zsh/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.config/zsh/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.config/zsh/.p10k.zsh

# Keybind - emacs style, enables ^f ^b ^a ^e ...
bindkey -e
bindkey '^p' history-search-backward
bindkey '^n' history-search-forward

# History
# -- some changes already in .zshenv file
setopt appendhistory # append to history file instead of overwritting
setopt sharehistory  # share command history between sessions
setopt hist_ignore_space # ignore commands starting with space 
setopt hist_ignore_dups
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups
setopt hist_save_no_dups
setopt hist_find_no_dups # Don't show duplicates in history search

# Completion styling
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zj}={A-Za-z}'
# Set the default colors to LS_COLORS
eval "$(dircolors -b)"
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors $LS_COLORS
zstyle ':completion:*' menu no
zstyle ':fzf-tab:complete:cd:*' fzf-preview 'ls --color $realpath' 
zstyle ':fzf-tab:complete:__zoxide_z:*' fzf-preview 'ls --color $realpath' 
  # ssh-agent configurations
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent quiet yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent agent-forwarding yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities ~/.ssh/github_rsa

# Aliases
alias ls='ls --color'
alias c='clear'
alias b='cd ..'

# Shell integrations
eval "$(fzf --zsh)" # Fuzzy finding
eval "$(zoxide init --cmd cd zsh)"

As you can see, for ssh-keys I am using:
zinit snippet OMZP::ssh-agent

and the following settings:
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent quiet yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent agent-forwarding yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities ~/.ssh/github_rsa

~/.ssh/github_rsa is the location of a valid key and has no password associated with it.
My ~/.ssh/config file is super simple. It only contains the line AddKeysToAgent yes.

Initially the problem I was facing was that no key was added to the agent.
Now, after some testing I found that the key only gets added to the agent if it has the default name id_ed25519, otherwise nothing happens ( at least with the values I tested for ) .
I couldn't test the loading of more than one key since they need to have different names, which means, different from the default which by my tests, doesn't work.
As suggested, I tried removing the setting zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes even if not recommended when using powerlevel10k. Weirdly enough, if the key has the default name it gets loaded anyways

Bear with me: you now have a id_ed25519 key that is being read, cool. Please do the following 1. Remove the identities line if it's still there 2. Generate another test key pair with ssh-keygen -t rsa, which should create a id_rsa key. What happens if you then restart your shell? Are both loaded? Just one? Which one?

@kos thanks for the suggestion! I did that and only have the snippet line. Both keys get loaded. I don't really understand why

Ok now what happens if you rename the id_ed25519 pair (both private and public keys) to github_rsa? Still both loaded? I'm unfamiliar with the plugin, it may be able to pick up on github_rsa automatically.

@kos no... If I do that only the id_rsa gets loaded. I think you can find the plugin code here

Now that I am thinking about it, there must be something wrong with the way I am defining the commands. If I define zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent quiet yes I still get output

Now what about removing lazy (going against the suggestion in the documentation) and using zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/github_rsa? Does that work? Although perhaps you would want to follow suggestion #2 in my answer.

As mentioned in ssh-agent plugin, under "Settings" / "identities" (emphasys not mine):

To load multiple identities use the identities style (this has no effect if the lazy setting is enabled).

So there is your problem.
However, as mentioned on the same page under "Settings" / "Powerline 10k specific settings":

Powerline10k has an instant prompt setting that doesn't like when this plugin writes to the console. Consider using the following settings if you're using p10k (documented above):
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent quiet yes
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes


So you may try and:

Ignore the warning under "Powerline 10k specific settings" and remove zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes. It's probably worth a shot. However, the wording under "identities" makes me think you may need to pass it more than one identity, so if simply removing zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes doesn't work and you want to load also your "default" identity anyways, try also changing zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities ~/.ssh/github_rsa to (assuming your "default" identity is ~/.ssh/id_rsa):
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/github_rsa


Not ignore the warning under "Powerline 10k specific settings" and try and follow the advice under "Settings" / "lazy":

You can enable AddKeysToAgent by passing -o AddKeysToAgent=yes to the ssh command, or by adding AddKeysToAgent yes to your ~/.ssh/config file




Thanks for the suggestions, already updated the question

@Educpf removing zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent lazy yes might not be enough if you keep passing a single identity to identities (because of the wording in the documentation), you should try and source another identity along with it (at least to see if it works). If you have a key you generated for your user (such as id_rsa), try adding that one along with ~/.ssh/github_rsa: zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/github_rsa. About ~/.ssh/config, please post the contents of the file, it's hard to tell what could be wrong with it without looking at it.

Sure thing, I really appreciate your help! I just found some weird things. I am going to update the question again.
